# How to change background image in external stylesheet with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to change the background image from external stylesheet.

For example in external stylesheet background image was:

```
#nav
  {
   background-image:url(../images/nav.png);
  }
```

Now i want to change it through javascript on run time like:

```
#nav
  {
   background-image:url(../images/newImg.png);
  }
```

I can successfully change this image by using this javascript code:

```
 eval('theRule.style.backgroundImage="../images/newImg.png"');
```

---

But issue is: Result looks like that:

```
#nav
  {
   background-image:url(http//localhost/project/images/newImg.png);
  }
```

I dont need **http//localhost/project/** etc...

I just need **../images/newImg.png**

I tried hard to fix this but i did not found any solution yet.

So Please guide me that how to resolve this issue?

Thanks for Reading my Question

Regards

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would answer your question but is one of those that I don't know where to begin, or how to actually explain it correctly so is understandable. I suggest you take a tour of JavaScript at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript) to grasp the basic concepts first.

Comment: Why can’t you just change the background image of the page, rather than changing the stylesheet?

Comment: If I set `url(../foo)` in CSS, then `getComputedStyle(elem)["background-image"]` already yields the full path. I don't think it makes any difference.

Comment: Actually, my requirement is that i have to change background image from stylesheet only. so that is why i need to get it resolved.

Comment: I'm afraid the result depends on the browser. May i ask what you're  finally trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to control my stylesheet rules through Javascript on run time. Everything is working fine with my code which i mentioned above but the problem is only that about URL of the background image... I pass some other value for the url of background and javascript make something else like url with http:// ... etc

Comment: But what's  problem you are faced with when the url starts with `http://...` ? Why do you need just `../images/newImg.png`

Comment: Because If i store the background image path through javascript then it save it in this shape: `http//localhost/project/images/newImg.png`
and it is saved in the stylesheet (styles.css). So when I upload it online server then http//localhost does not mean anything and it will not load the image. But Image path will be `../images/newImg.png` then it will automatically find the right image from the right path.

Answer (score 1):

Try.

```
rule.style.setProperty("background-image", "../images/newImg.png", "");
rule.style.cssText = rule.style.cssText.replace("../images/nav.png", "../images/newImg.png"); //Replace all images
```

But if not helped, then do not find easy ways.